# Draw line on google map in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive

I want when map loaded, a straight line between two city drawed e.g. pecan and London.
How I can draw a straight line between two city on Google map with angularjs?

Comment: depends if you are going to use the angularjs google maps directive, or just want to use the google maps api as is

Comment: I use ionic google mape template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drawing `Simple Polylines`, you can save `latitude` and `longitude` in `arrays` like this:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
```

Then, use `google.maps.Polyline` draw them out.

```
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple).